# video tag inline in ionic with ios playsinline works first time

Tags: ionic-framework, html5-video

I am using below js

[inline video play js for ios](https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video)

for display inline video in ios with ionic that is working perfectly.

but with that project i am using `themeable browser` plugin for display external links once i open themeable browser video player stopped working inline. They start playing in fullscreen.

[Pugin for themeable browser](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/themeable-browser/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add one line in DidStartLoad function in below file.

### File Location

```
platforms->ios->appName->Plugins->cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser->CDVThemeableBrowser.m
```

### Function in file

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    theWebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
}
```

Hope that will work for you.